# jquery validation remote method

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

i'm new to jquery, trying to add a validation rule to my email input. It checks if email is in database or not.
my html input i'm trying to add validation rule to.

```
<input id="email" name="email"  type="text" class="easyui-validatebox" validType="email" required="true" >
```

MY JS

```
$("#regform").validate();//block below was nested in validate in OP 
$('input[name="email"]').rules("add",
{
    remote : 
    {
        url: 'checkMaila.php',
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
            email: function()
            {
                return $('input[name="email"]').val()
            }
        }       
    }

});
```

MY PHP

```
<?php
```

/* check if email is already registered */

//connect to db using mysqli

```
include 'conn.php';

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    //op had this line instead of the line below:$maila= $_POST['email']
    $maila = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    //op line changed to one below $result = mysql_query("select * from user where email= '"+$maila+"';");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '".$maila."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql); 
if($result->num_rows == 0){
    echo "true";
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}

}
else
{
echo "false"; //invalid post var
}

?>
```

more info:
my inline validation rules work as they should. my js code is in external js file which contains other js functions using jquery, they work.

Comment: You shouldn't nest `.rules()` inside of `.validate()`.

Comment: I have tryed with and with out validate() and other variations from a a post i read here it said it is needed to initialize the validation.The problem is when I input an email in the text box that is already in the database it should show error msg "please fix this". also is there any way to trouble shoot js problems i used try catch not a great help.

Comment: Despite still having other problems, I am telling you that nesting `.rules()` inside of `.validate()` is not correct under any circumstances.  [Read the documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules)

Comment: Please don't radically edit your OP like that, it disconnects previous answers and renders them useless to others.  Please _amend_ your OP if you need to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is for this much earlier revision of the OP:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13380448/2

---

You should not have `.rules()` nested inside of `.validate()`.  [As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules), `.rules()` must also appear someplace *after* `.validate()` is invoked.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#regform").validate();  

    // .validate(); must appear above .rules()

    $('input[name="email"]').rules("add", {
        remote : {
            url: 'checkMaila.php',
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                email: function() {
                    return $('input[name="email"]').val()
                }
            }       
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$maila` to a boolean (Whether `$_POST['email']` is set or not). Should be:

```
$maila = $_POST['email'];
```

Also the email data in post should be validated and escaped before it is executed in sql, this is because of SQL injection. If I put in `10'; DROP TABLE user /*` then the query executed looks like: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '10'; DROP TABLE user /*'` and your user table will be dropped from the database.

To validate it use regex to check that it is of an email address format. To escape the string use `real_escape_string()` (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Another error you have is that your attempting to join your string using `+`, in php you have to use `.`, so

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '"+$maila+"'";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '".$maila."'";
```

mysql as used here : `mysql_query` is deprecated and so either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) should be used instead.

In the jQuery there is also a problem, rules shouldn't be nested inside validate, instead it should be like this:

```
$("#regform").validate();

$('input[name="email"]').rules("add", {
    ...
```

Comment: ah i may have over looked this I changed it to see if there was a problem in my php. ty for pointing it out.

Comment: i know of sql injection and how to counter it in php. i wanted to learn jquery so i am doing this small registration form. this code will not go on a live site.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Before you start with ajax make sure, that your php source is working find, so you can find errors in specified content (php|html|js|css) easier.

The first big errors i've seen on your php code:

```
 $maila = isset($_POST['email']);
```

You have to set $maila to boolean true or false, what you want is

```
 $maila = isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
```

The second error

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '"+$maila+"'";
```

This is no valid php (look in your error reporting) strings are connected by a dot **.**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '".$maila."'";
```

And last but not least, take a search for sql-injections